# In Grunt, no targets found

Tags: coffeescript, gruntjs

I am trying to build a project using Grunt with all the source in coffeescript.  To start with I want to run all the source through coffeelint.  My Gruntfile.coffee is:

```
#  Gruntfile for base code for Polyglot

module.exports = ->
  @initConfig

  @loadNpmTasks 'grunt-coffeelint'

  coffeelint:
    all:["*.coffee"]

  @registerTask "default",["coffeelint"]
```

I do:

grunt

and get:

> > No "coffeelint" targets found.

I am expecting to lint Gruntfile.coffee.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Gruntfile is expected to have a function with an argument in it:

```
module.exports = (grunt)->
  grunt.initConfig

  grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-coffeelint'

  coffeelint:
    all:["*.coffee"]

  grunt.registerTask "default",["coffeelint"]
```

EDIT: also coffeelint's task configuration should be nested within `initConfig`, and coffeelint does not take `all` as a part of its configuration. Perhaps you mean `app`?:

```
module.exports = (grunt)->
  grunt.initConfig
    coffeelint:
      app:["*.coffee"]

  grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-coffeelint'
  grunt.registerTask "default",["coffeelint"]
```

Comment: Watch out for another occurance of `grunt.initConfig` if your Gruntfile is too long. It may overwrite the settings...